# Trying to achieve YouTube-like full-screen video handling with Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to achieve something similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60645582/youtube-like-fullscreen-button-on-flutter), but here I'm also gonna talk about my attempt.

In short, I just wanna achieve the same full-screen functionality as YouTube.

- When the user tapped on the full-screen icon, the video becomes full screen in landscape and it stays like that even though the user keeps holding the device vertically. The video will be automatically minimized if the device is rotated to portrait **after** the device **had been rotated to landscape**.
- If the user does not lock the device rotation, the video will be put in full screen when the device is tilted to landscape and will be minimized when tilted back to portrait.
- If the video is being played on full screen, tapping the full-screen icon will minimize the video and also put the app orientation to portrait regardless of the way user holds the device.

---

Here is my attempt at achieving the above behaviors with Flutter:

- App's preferred orientation is not set (allows both landscape and portrait)
- Watch for orientation change. Programmatically put the video on full screen if the current orientation is landscape and minimize the video in portrait.
- Set the app's preferred orientation to landscape when the full-screen icon is tapped. (The video will be on full screen)
- To allow users to physically rotate the device back to portrait set preferred orientations to both portrait and landscape after 1 second.

```
 // Tapped on full-screen icon
 SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
    <DeviceOrientation>[
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
    ],
 );

 await Future.delayed(
    const Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
 );

 // Allow rotating physically back to portrait
 SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
    <DeviceOrientation>[
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
      DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    ],
 );
```

- The code above works as expected on an iOS device as iPhone does not immediately change its orientation back to portrait when the preferred orientation is set back to both landscape and portrait while the device is being held vertically.

The problem here is with Android devices.

After 1 second, if the device is still being held vertically, the app orientation will change to portrait which is not the desired behavior.

Is there any practical way to achieve my desired behaviors? I strongly believe that what I have done is not even close to how YouTube does it.

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Comment: Not really, I've been using something like what I mentioned in the post.